# Unable to submit specified field using Malsups jquery ajaxSubmit() plugin

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am normally using $.ajax() function to transfer my data. But now i need to upload a file in my form and its not possible using $.ajax() function so i decided to use malsup's ajaxSubmit plugin([Malsup's plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#ajaxSubmit)). My form is somewhat big and complex, its including lot of selection process using radio buttons and checkbooks, i can't send form datas to php page in this format. So when form submits i validate all fields and stored in a javascript variable in a simple format so it is easier to process in php.
My data variable look like this:

```
var value="{name=jack,age=18}";
```

which is in the form of data which can be send additional with ajaxForm().

 This is how ajaxSubmit() function calls:

```
 var data={
    url:"action.php",
    data:value,
    type:'POST',
    dataType:'json',
    success:function(r)
    {
        alert(r.msg);
    }
$("#form").ajaxSubmit(data);
```

But here ajaxSubmit() function serialize all the data in the form and send it with the data in the variable.
 I just wanted to serialize only the file upload fields and send it with the data in variable. Please help me to work this out.